# Any chance of getting back money I lent?

Tags: debt

A few years years ago I lent 50,000$ to a friend in financial trouble and we agreed he'd pay me back when he was able to (though I have no evidence of this other than the bank transaction).

We had an argument a while ago over his gambling addiction, and we stopped talking. A few days ago I discovered he won 900000$. I asked him if he could pay back the 50000$ I lent him, and he said no because "I didn't believe in him".

I mentioned him that we agreed he'd pay me back when he was doing ok financially, and he clearly is, but he insists I agreed the money was a gift.

Is there anything that can be done legally in such a situation, or is that money gone?

Comment: While the typical answer is that one can never loan money like that to friends (it either ends up turning into a gift or breaks the friendship), I do find it interesting that he thinks the money was a gift, but that you "didn't believe in him."  There may be a useful related question you could ask on Interpersonal.SE along those lines.

Comment: Too much for small claims, and no documents documenting it was a loan... Hard.

Answer (score -1):

> Is there anything that can be done legally in such a situation, or is that money gone?

You will need to use skill so that he --perhaps inadvertently-- admits that the transaction was a loan as opposed to a gift. Your communications need to be *in writing* so you can file them in court if you succeed in obtaining his admission.

Beware that the statements "*You didn't believe in me*" and "*That was a gift*" do not necessarily contradict each other. For instance, a person can give money to a beggar as a gift without expecting/trusting the beggar will succeed or get any far. You need to secure from the debtor statements or admissions that preclude him from giving an alternative credible explanation that "harmonizes" his otherwise inconsistent statements.

It is unclear from your post whether you can resort to any witnesses. Their sworn testimony (be it deposition, affidavit, or the like) can weigh on the parties' credibility.

If you file suit, consider conducting discovery on the debtor's bank accounts (and perhaps the counterparties involved). His gambling addiction suggests he might have obtained significant amount of money from others as well. His transaction history might ultimately lead to evidence that discredits his allegation that your money was a gift. This does not mean that what is known as "*other acts evidence*" will prove your case. In fact, there evidentiary rules prohibit that. But evidentiary rules permit the use of "*other acts evidence*" as proof of a person's intent, scheme, or system in doing an act. See, for instance, [MRE 404(b)(1)](https://courts.michigan.gov/Courts/MichiganSupremeCourt/rules/Documents/Michigan%20Rules%20of%20Evidence.pdf).

There might be other circumstantial evidence available to you, although this is not apparent from the information you have provided so far.

Comment: The statute of limitations doesn't start ticking when the loan is created, it starts ticking at the moment of non-payment.  With repayment terms of "when he's able to", a lawyer who is even modestly competent will argue that the statute of limitations only started ticking a few days ago, with the refusal to re-pay despite being able to.

Comment: @Mark You're so right. Can't believe I missed that crucial detail. Thanks!